Prove that $\sin (\sqrt{x})$ is greater than $\sin(x)$ in $[0,1]$
While I was doing a question, an inequality comes into my calculations:
$$\sin(\sqrt {x}) \geq \sin x \text{ for the interval of } [0,1]$$
Here is my thought:
Define a function $f(x) = \sin(\sqrt {x}) - \sin x$, in the interval of $[0,1]$, this function has 2 zeros, which is $x=0$ and $x=1$
The derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x) =\frac{\cos (\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}} - \cos x$, which is positive on the interval of $[0,b]$, where $b$ is a number that I can't determine right now, that means $f(x)$ is an increasing function in the interval $[0,b]$.
Also note that $f(x)$ is continuous, initially increasing  and it only has 2 zeros in the interval, meaning that in the interval of $[0,1]$, there is only two point where it touches x-axis, ($x=0$ and $x=1$), for all other $x$ in the interval, $f(x)>0$, which prove the inequality in the beginning.
However I cannot prove that $f(x)$ only has 2 zeros in the interval, which I need help with, and I think this method is not elegant enough, I want to look for more simple way to prove it.
Any help is appreciated

You're overcomplicating things, in my opinion. I would proceed as so:

Show $\sin x$ is increasing on $[0,1]$
Show $\sqrt x \ge x$ on $[0,1]$
Then the result immediately follows by the fact that, if $f$ is monotone-increasing, $x \ge y \implies f(x) \ge f(y)$.


For $x=t^2,\ 0\le t\le 1,$ we have  $$ \sin t-\sin t^2=2\sin {t(1-t)\over 2}\cos{t(1+t)\over 2}\ge 0 $$ as all arguments  showing up belong to $[0,\pi/2],$ where $\sin $ and $\cos $ are nonnegative. The inequality is strict provided that $0<x<1.$
